How does a neural network differentiate between a neuron that outputs 0 and a dropped-out one?
How does a network differentiate between a neuron with output 0 and a dropped-out neuron (this neuron might output a non-zero value but due to dropout it outputs 0)?

During training or at prediction time?

Both. I suspect that during training a non-dropped out neuron that outpus 0 still contributes to the gradient whereas a dropped-out one doesn't.

It doesn't.  In some perspectives of drop-out, that's the whole point.  The idea being that reliance on and sensitivity to any particular neuron's value is reduced if the neuron can be randomly set to zero and the network still functions.
